# generate data from statistical distribution and properties

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner of python and statistics.

I want to generate synthetic data based on the statistical properties that I get from `pd.describe()` and a data distribution profile from my dataset.

Here is what the statistical properties look like:

[image: statistical properties]

And the distribution is:

[image: dataset distribution]

Is there a way or any reference on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It is okay, if I ignore the constraints of 25th, 50th and 75th percentile?

Comment: actually, i did with min, max, std, and mean from scipy library with this function:
dist = stats.truncnorm((min_val - mean) / std, (max_val - mean) / std, loc=mean, scale=std).
with those function, the dataset become normal distribution, and the statistical properties also change.
let say we ignore the percentile, how to include the real dataset distribution properties?